# how to read a specific key press from a specific device in python

Tags: python, hid

is there any way to read a keyboard key from a specific keyboard device in python?

i basically want to make a app like [HID macros](https://www.hidmacros.eu/) using python. if not possible please show me if there are any alternatives.

Answer (score -2):

ok so i forgot that i should run HID macros as an administrator.